# PHP manipulate timezone?

Tags: php, time

If i have date can I add different timezone?

e.g. i have  1/1/2000 5pm  in +2gmt i need to add +4gmt = 1/1/2000 7pm
or substract -6gmt from thjis so i will get 1pm?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php). There's also a [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class that allows you to specify an interval that you can use with `DateTime::add` and `DateTime::sub`.

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . PHP_EOL;

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

**Outputs:**

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00+12:00
2000-01-01 01:45:00+13:45
```